# Remove outer element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div>
    <p>
        <img>
    </p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

How to remove the first `<p></p>` but not the childs (img)?

Comment: Look into `.unwrap()` http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Answer (score 5):

you can use .unwrap()

to unwrap the first p you have to specify the select as first() p also

```
 $("p").first().contents().unwrap()
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
$("p").first().contents().unwrap()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>
<img>
</p>
<p>aaa
</p>
<p>
</p>
</div>
```